# TRIGGER para modificar valores después de un INSERT en otra tabla

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, condiciones, trigger

Debo hacer un trigger el cual después de un insert en la tabla 'jornadas' se modifica la cantidad de puntos en la tabla 'equipos' en función del resultado.

El trigger es el siguiente y creo que el código es correcto.

```
drop trigger if exists puntos;
delimiter $$

CREATE TRIGGER puntos
AFTER INSERT ON jornadas FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE equipo_Local int;
    DECLARE equipo_Visitante int;
    DECLARE goles_Local int;
    DECLARE goles_Visitante int;

SELECT equipo_local, equipo_visitante, goles_local, goles_visitante INTO equipo_Local, equipo_Visitante, goles_Local, goles_Visitante FROM jornadas;

    IF goles_Local > goles_Visitante THEN
        UPDATE equipos SET puntos = puntos + 3 WHERE equipoID = equipo_Local;
    ELSE IF goles_Local < goles_Visitante THEN
        UPDATE equipos SET puntos = puntos + 3 WHERE equipoID = equipo_Visitante;
    ELSE 
        UPDATE equipos SET puntos = puntos + 1 WHERE equipoID IN (equipo_Local, equipo_Visitante);
    END IF;
END$$
delimiter ;
```

El tema está en que me da un error al final del mismo que no consigo solucionar por más modificaciones que hago. El error es el siguiente:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 18
```

¿Alguna solución?

Comment: Si comentas / retiras todo el if/else if/else e intentas crear el trigger nuevamente, sigue fallando?

Comment: Tengo todo el código en un archivo .sql con toda la estructura y creación de tablas y al final pongo el trigger y voy modificándolo y haciendo source del archivo para ver si está todo OK. Y no hay manera de que entre. Me da el fallo en la línea 18 en la parte de 'END$$'.

Comment: Si quitas el Trigger por completo de ese archivo, falla?? si no es demasiado extenso y no tiene líos legales, puedes ponerlo acá. Puede ser un error tipográfico que no tenga que ver. O si lo pones en un archivo separado para no enredar el uso del delimitador

Comment: La causa del error de sintaxis es el `ELSE IF`, debe ser `ELSEIF` (sin el espacio en blanco). Sin embargo, el disparador (trigger) luego de creado, al ejecutarse seguramente fallará por el `SELECT` ya que posiblemente devuelva más de una fila. Recuerde, los disparadores (triggers) operan a nivel de fila (FOR EACH ROW), es decir, por cada inserción en la tabla `jornadas` se ejecutará el disparador (trigger) con los valores de esa inserción.